# problem with website format using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I justified my text in div tags. when I reduce the size of the page, subsequently the div tags become smaller (because the site is responsive) but there is too much empty space between the words. is there a way to solve this problem? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxL6X.jpg)

another question is that I have four div tags (black ones) just like in the picture. I want to make them smaller(as big as red ones). I used width and height and in the PC browser it works fine but for mobile devices, the margins that have been produced by making the div tags smaller make it not to fit the mobile screen. if I give the height and width are not 100%, when the page shrinks the texts are stretched out of div border. need some help here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIEwG.jpg)

this code is for 4 div tags.

```
.first-1{              
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;    
    display: inline-flex;        
}
.second-2{ 
    
    
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline-flex;       
}

}
#first-e{
  
    border: solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 40%;
    height:40%;      
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0px 10px 40px 10px;
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    align-content: center;       
}
#second-e{
  
    border: solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 40%;
    height:40%; 
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0px 10px 40px 10px;
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 10px;
    text-align: justify;       
}
#third-e{
   
    border: solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 40%;
    height:40%; 
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0px 10px 40px 10px;
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 10px;
    text-align: justify;       
}
#fourth-e{       
    border: solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 40%;
    height:40%; 
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0px 10px 40px 10px;
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 10px;   
    text-align: justify;    
}
```

Comment: 1st: please provide all the necessary code so that we can edit it to make it work and see what you actually did. 2nd: For the issue with the spacings it is because you have a block-style text. it will enforce to expend over the entire possible width and create spacings to make sure it can do that. if you have a normal styled text espacially with word-wrap you always will get the same spacings.

Comment: 3rd it is proberly a fundemental issue as I see it. The problem is, that you believe that responsive soley means that it wil automatically resize to the screen. Its actually only sem-responsive. clean-responsive (fullresponsive) means, that the layout will change through media queries to adjust to a mobile screen. Then the layout will differt to be easier to read, having pictures at a size that is still useable and buttons and fontsize in a size that you can read and touch them still on touchscreens with bigger fingers. Best start learning to use a grid and media queries!

Comment: Thanks for adding the CSS, add the HTML please aswell. Noone not going to guess what you did. We need enough code (HTML, JS and CSS) provided to recreate the issue. If I going to write the code, I cant recreate the issue as I will write it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The first one you can just add a paragraph for a text like this:

**HTML**

```
<p>Text goes here</p>
```

and the second one You can use floats for that on CSS like this:

**CSS**

```
.className {
   float: right;
}
```

Comment: you are also new, otherwise you should know not to anwser those question and instead comment them. Because right now, you also guessing as you dont actually know what the OP did.

Comment: whats OP @tacoshy

Comment: OP = Original Poster ( the one that started the thread, asked the question)

Comment: Side note: There is a Stack Overflow [glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420).

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem try using
`word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: will not do a thing. there problery are not word breaks programmed into the larger words. As she also has no "-" or "/" symbols inside her words, they will not break clean on their own. The problems are fundemental here. They are because OP is pretty new and tries to implement a responsive design that does not work well on mobile devices. Its just lack of experience and missing base knowledge about the right tools to use as media queries.